# Как разобрать подобные виды данных?

Tags: java, xml, xmlparser

Допустим есть строчка из xml файла:

```
<Item name="название" image="Картинка" id="id" ItemsCraft="33:44:24:0:55:0:22:66:77"  price="цена"/>
```

Меня интересует атрибут `ItemsCraft="33:44:24:0:55:0:22:66:77"`
Как взять каждое число через двоеточие в отдельную перемену, тем самым разобрать его?
Понятное дело можно сделать по тупому и просто вот так:

```
ItemCraft1 ="33"
ItemCraft2 ="44"
ItemCraft3 ="24"
ItemCraft4 ="0"
ItemCraft5 ="55"
ItemCraft6 ="0"
ItemCraft7 ="22"
ItemCraft8 ="66"
ItemCraft9 ="77"
```

Это не правильно и громоздко. 
Хм... `split();` ...

Comment: Зачем в отдельную? Не разумнее будет использовать список?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `split();`всё решил.
Вопрос закрыт.

```
String str1 = "33:44:24:0:55:0:22:66:77";
    String[] str2;

    str2 = str1.split(":");

    for(String _string : str2){
        System.out.println(_string);
    }
```